# Singular matrix proof

Tags: matrices

Let $A,B$ are real orthogonal matrices of an odd order $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Prove that at least one matrix of the form $A+B$ and $A−B$ has to be singular.

For $n=3$ we can choose $A=B=        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}$ and $A-B$ is zero-matrix which is singular.

But $A+B=\begin{bmatrix}
        2 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 2 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 2 \\
        \end{bmatrix}$ which is not singular.

What method or theorem to use for finding such $A,B$ that will prove the statement?

Comment: If we don't assume $A \ne B$, we can always just get the zero matrix.

Comment: @EliRose I expect that the point is to prove that this holds for _all_ such pairs of matrices.

Answer (score 3):

Let $ C = A^TB $, assume that both $ A+B$, $ A-B $ are invertible. $ A^T $ is invertible, implying $ A^T(A+B) = I+C $ and $ A^T(A-B) = I-C $ are both invertible. However, $ C $ is a $ n \times n $ orthogonal matrix with $ n $ odd, so there exists a real eigenvalue of $ C $, $ \lambda $ and $ \lambda \in \{ -1, 1 \} $. But, $ \lambda = 1 $ implies $ 0 $ is an eigenvalue of $ I-C $, while $ \lambda = -1 $ implies $ 0 $ is an eigenvalue of $ I+C $, contradiction. Hence, atleast one of $ A+B$, $ A-B $ is singular.